# xsl foreach loop not working on xml

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I've been trying to iterate through an XML file using XSL , however I'm having major troubles as the only first language is being recognised.  Help!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<languages count="1">
  <language>English (UK)</language>
  <language>Spanish</language>
  <language>Arabic</language>
</languages>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="languages">
              <th>
                 <xsl:value-of select="language"/>
              </th>
          </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only have one `languages` node, at the root.

You should be using templates instead of `for-each` whenever possible:

```
<xsl:template match="language">
    <th>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </th>
</xsl:template>
```

And in the main template call it:

```
<tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="languages/language"/>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

@Oded has probably posted the best answer atm, try to go with that. But in your specific case, you've written

```
<xsl:for-each select="languages">
```

of which there is only one, so rewrite that as

```
<xsl:for-each select="languages/language">
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="language">
```

as

```
<xsl:value-of select=".">
```

or

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

and this particular stylesheet should work for you.

So again: if you can, do what Oded suggests. Sometimes though, you will have to use a for-each-loop - if so, then hopefully my answer helps you understand what you did wrong in this case.